# Unexpected distortion in injected html code to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think this is a weird issue... And maybe another bug!

I insert html via `innerHTML` to a div like this:

```js
const verbs = ['leave', 'left', 'left'];
const insertion = `${getSpans()}`;
const elem = document.getElementById("container");
elem.innerHTML = insertion;

function getSpans() {
    let result = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < verbs.length; i++) {
    const verb = verbs[i];
    if(i === 0){ 
      result += `<tspan id="span1">${verb.trim()}</tspan>`; 
      result += '<tspan fill="#fcba03"> - </tspan>';
    } else if(i === 1) {
      result += `<tspan id="span2">${verb.trim()}</tspan>`; 
      result += '<tspan fill="#fcba03"> - </tspan>';
    } else {
      result += `<tspan id="span3">${verb.trim()}</tspan>`
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Here everything works fine and as you see the hyphens between verbs seem to be separated with a single space between each word.

I did the exact same thing in my code (I can not reproduce it here because its consists of multiple files and etc) but the first hyphen seem to be attached to the `leave` verb!!! I mean there is no space after `leave` verb...

Here is a proof of what I say:

[image]

And what makes it weird is although I'm 100 percent sure that the insertion string into `innerHTML` is correct (you can see the spans in above image in console) the issue happens.

Also if I make an update in the page like zooming in or out everything get fixed!

What am I missing and how to fix this? Any comments would be appreciated...

Comment: Not an answer or related to the problem but your `getSpan()` can be simplified to: `function getSpan() { return verbs.map(function(verb, index) { return \`<tspan id="span${index + 1}">${verb.trim()}</tspan>\` }).join('<tspan fill="#fcba03"> - </tspan>'); }`

Comment: space maybe be removed in your processing. Perhaps replace it with another character to test it works with that. You could try replacing space with &nbsp; or &#160;